# Firewall exceptions required for ADAL.NET

Tags: c#, azure, adal, azure-active-directory

Our prod app is behind a very strict firewall. We are seeing that during login, the ADAL.NET+AzureAD web app tries to talk to an IP Address in the Microsoft Azure network (most likely to validate the auth request). While this is understandable, we need to know what IP Addresses/Ports/Protocols we need to allow in the firewall. And I can't find any definitive documentation about it.

The best bit of info I can find so far is * https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-URLs-and-IP-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2  .. which is like 500IPaddresses, and a ridiculous # of firewall exceptions that no IT admin will allow (impossible to manage).

Is there a simple guide that I'm missing? I've google/bing'ed the crap out of it with no avail. TIA!

S

Answer (score 0):

ADAL.NET speaks OpenID Connect. Which is a standard protocol based on the OAuth 2.0 framework. This is pure Web protocol and talks exclusively and only over HTTPS - so you need an outgoing TCP connection on port 443.

As for concrete IP Address - no. This is cloud. You cannot get a single IP adress, not even a range, for a service and rely it will remain the same. The best you can do, and which is doable on Firewalls, is to all outgoing TCP connections on port 443 with destnation DNS name including:

- login.microsoftonline.com
- login.windows.net

These are relatively simple to implement.

Comment: Thanks. We did add outgoint TCP to *microsoftonline.com and *.windows.net - and that wasn't enough. I realize its cloud - but try telling it to security minded people who don't want internet connectivity on their production servers (or any server in that segment). Frankly, you can't blame them. It would be good to have a simple firewall rule that can be setup - and Microsoft has documented a range of URLs and IP Addresses, but .. 500 IPs is not the answer.

Comment: Well, you haven't described what **exact** application you have and how **exact** you configured the ADAL and how **exact** you configured the application in Azure AD. So you got a **best guess** answer. There are of course other options to go Cloud without even going through Internet. But you have to be a bit mroe specific about your **exact** situation and expectations ...

Comment: I have a WebAPI written in ASPNET 4.x.
Front end is a JavaScript SPA (native app).
Requests come in with bearer tokens - and the backend needs to talk out to AzureAD to verify the authentication. That request (from WebAPI to AzureAD) is being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue by routing all traffic through a proxy. The server with the WebAPI can be onprem and the proxy (if you wish) can be in Azure. Here is the solution for the next poor soul butting heads with their IT Admins - 
http://blah.winsmarts.com/2016-5-Routing_all_application_traffic_through_a_proxy.aspx